# What does には mean in this case?

Tags: grammar, reading-comprehension

The sentence in question:

> 休日の繁華街は平和な賑わいに満ちていた。道行く人々の笑顔は眩しく、街灯はどこまでも明るく、一足早いクリスマス模様のショウウィンドウ**には**、まるで世界中の幸せを寄せ集めて詰め込んだように華やかだった。

I would normally think of には following after something like ショウウィンドウ to talk about the "contents" inside, but this isn't possible here since it ends with 華やかだった, right? Does it just mean "as for ～" in this case?

Edit: I suppose another possible interpretation would be 華やかだった referring to the entire 繁華街, but I'm rather unsure on that due to where には is placed.

Comment: "but this isn't possible here since it ends with 華やかだった" <- Why do you think this? Why not "It was gorgeous **in** the pre-christmas display windows, like all the world's happiness had been squeezed into them"?

Comment: I thought if that was the case it would've been 華やかさがあった instead.

Comment: I got a native's opinion and it seems that まるで世界中の幸せを寄せ集めて詰め込んだように is describing the window itself, while 華やかだった is talking about the shopping district. I guess that's more intuitive, but the grammar of it still strikes me as odd.

Comment: I read the text over several times and I strongly feel this is a simple mistake. It should be ショウウィンドウは(華やかだった), or (ショウウィンドウには)華やかさがあった as you say.